# What’s the simplest way (in PHP) to grab a remote HTTP resource into a string?

Tags: php, curl

I do not want to download it to a file.

Note also that I cannot use `file_get_contents` because my web host disabled that option.

Comment: How about [cURL](http://us3.php.net/curl)?

Comment: The docs are so long and the examples are for downloading a file with curl. … was really hoping I wouldn’t have to read all of them for what should, in theory, be a one-liner…

Comment: It's only a one-liner if your host allows it.

Comment: Curl worked with the right options. Crazy. I feel so much safer now that the one-line option is disabled but the five-line option still works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try using `cURL` :**

```
function curlFile($url,$proxy_ip="",$proxy_port="",$loginpassw="")
{
    //$loginpassw = 'username:password';
    //$proxy_ip = '192.168.1.1';
    //$proxy_port = '12345';
    //$url = 'http://www.domain.com';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, $proxy_port);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, 'HTTP');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy_ip);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $loginpassw);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use CURL.

[PHP CURL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)